# Include java script structure inside a string

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-studio-2.2

I am working on a personal offline java book for myself 
there are some codes which I want to show as it is inside a string but error says 
"Error parsing XML: not well formed(invalid token)"
I know that there is some keyword or some symbol inside the string that might not come the way I m writing it.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ruralshores_skills_academy.app.Activity2"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="2dp">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Example Programs"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        android:textColor="#400407"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Most of the example programs given in the text are ready to be executed and are similar in form to:
        class Test&#009;{
        public static void main(String[&#032;] args)&#009;{
        &#009;&#009;for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        &#009;&#009;&#009;System.out.print(i == 0 ? args[i] : '' '' + args[i]);
        &#009;&#009;System.out.println();
        &#009;}
        }"/>
       </ScrollView>
```

I am pretty sure that the problem is the string cause before that the app is working fine
The error code starts to appear as soon as I put the third line which contains the for loop

Comment: How is this related to android?

Comment: @Sweeper Sir its a part of an android ebook I m making so thts y I placed android in the tags

Comment: The error that you had given it's not related with this part of the code. The problem is that the XML file you are attempting to parse has a malformed structure so we will need to look up to you XML to see what's wrong.

Comment: Post the complete stack trace, and the relevant code snippet which is causing this problem, because the code you posted is likely not to generate this kind of exception

Comment: "for(int i = 0;i<args.length;i++)" here is the error when we put this line in a string we get the error. without it the app works fine

Comment: so android:text="for(int i = 0;i<args.length;i++)" gives an error.                                        android:text="anything" does not